My Python's Minesweeper function is returning different values when it should be constant values
I wrote a Minesweeper in Python using a class, the random  and the Numpy modules. By choosing the difficulty, it sets up the dimension of the board and creates it, with the help of Numpy. It, then, randomly sets up mines across the board, also according to the difficulty chosen.
When you make a play, a specific function checks the 8 cells around the point you chose to step and returns the amount of mines present there.
After some fixing, I ran the code for the final time in hopes that it would be working just fine... what I got in return were different values for the same position after making different plays.
I checked every function and the path the program was taking at every play, but I was still unable to find where it was making this mistake.
Since the code is quite big for this site, here's the OnlineGDB link instead:
https://onlinegdb.com/JxHI-lRdP
A quick preview:
def setupMines(self, mines: int = 15) -> None:
        if len(self.board) <= 5: raise ValueError('Board too small')
        self.mines = set()
        while len(self.mines) < mines:
            rand_row = randint(0, self.__dimension - 1)
            rand_col = randint(0, self.__dimension - 1)
            self.mines.add((rand_row, rand_col))
        for row, col in self.mines:
            self.board[row][col] = 1
    
    def makePlay(self, row: int, col: int) -> None:
        self.row = row - 1
        self.column = col - 1
        if self.board[row - 1][col - 1] == 1:
            for i in 'You stepped on a mine!\nEnding program...':
                print(i, end='')
                wait(0.07)
            exit(0)
        elif self.board[row - 1][col - 1] == 0:
            self.board[row - 1][col - 1] = -1
            self.printBoard()
        self.EndGame()
    
    def checkPlay(self) -> int:
        tip = 0
        aux_row = -1
        for _ in range(3):
            aux_column = -1
            for _ in range(3):
                if (self.row + aux_row, self.column + aux_column) in self.mines: tip += 1
                aux_column += 1
            aux_row += 1
        return tip


That's because of how the checkPlay method is called within the printBoard method.
Each time you call checkPlay, it rechecks the mines around the current position (self.row, self.column), which can change as you make new plays. This causes the same position to likely give different mine counts after different plays.
Make sure that each cell’s mine count is calculated once and stored; where checkPlay results are stored and printed correctly:
import numpy as np
from random import randint
from time import sleep as wait
from sys import exit

class MineBoard:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.dialogue()

    def setupBoard(self, dimension: int = 9):
        if not isinstance(dimension, int):
            raise TypeError(f'Expected a type: int, instead got type:{type(dimension)}')
        self.__dimension = dimension
        self.board = np.zeros(shape=(dimension, dimension))
        self.revealed_board = np.full((dimension, dimension), '-')
    
    def setupMines(self, mines: int = 15) -> None:
        if len(self.board) <= 5: raise ValueError('Board too small')
        self.mines = set()
        while len(self.mines) < mines:
            rand_row = randint(0, self.__dimension - 1)
            rand_col = randint(0, self.__dimension - 1)
            self.mines.add((rand_row, rand_col))
        for row, col in self.mines:
            self.board[row][col] = 1
    
    def makePlay(self, row: int, col: int) -> None:
        self.row = row - 1
        self.column = col - 1
        if self.board[row - 1][col - 1] == 1:
            for i in 'You stepped on a mine!\nEnding program...':
                print(i, end='')
                wait(0.07)
            exit(0)
        elif self.board[row - 1][col - 1] == 0:
            self.revealed_board[row - 1][col - 1] = self.checkPlay()
            self.printBoard()
        self.EndGame()
    
    def checkPlay(self) -> int:
        tip = 0
        for i in range(max(0, self.row - 1), min(self.__dimension, self.row + 2)):
            for j in range(max(0, self.column - 1), min(self.__dimension, self.column + 2)):
                if (i, j) in self.mines: tip += 1
        return tip
    
    def printBoard(self) -> str:
        for i in range(self.__dimension):
            print('\n')
            for j in range(self.__dimension):
                print(self.revealed_board[i][j], end='\t')
    
    def EndGame(self) -> None:
        scanner = list()
        for i in self.board:
            auxiliar = [x for x in i if x == -1]
            scanner += auxiliar
        if len(scanner) == 0:
            for i in 'Congratulations, you beat the game!!':
                print(i, end='')
                wait(0.3)
            exit(0)
        else: return

    def dialogue(self) -> None:
        print('''\n\nMINESWEEPER\n\n''')
        wait(1.0)
        print('''Tip: Maximize the terminal.\n''')
        wait(1.5)
        choice = int(input('''CHOOSE YOUR DIFFICULTY:
(1) - Easy
(2) - Medium
(3) - Hard

--->> '''))
        match choice:
            case 1:
                self.setupBoard()
                self.setupMines()
            case 2:
                self.setupBoard(15)
                self.setupMines(40)
            case 3:
                self.setupBoard(20)
                self.setupMines(75)
        
        while True:
            print(f'\n\nMake your play! Choose a line and a column! {self.__dimension} by {self.__dimension}')
            row = int(input('\nLine: '))
            col = int(input('Column: '))
            self.makePlay(row=row, col=col)

MineBoard()

Added self.revealed_board to store the revealed state of the board; makePlay updates self.revealed_board with the result from checkPlay; checkPlay calculates the number of mines around the specified cell once, and printBoard prints the values from self.revealed_board.
This ensures that each cell's mine count is calculated and stored once, preventing the issue of inconsistent values for the same position across different plays.
Have fun!
